# How can I fix the 'web-justifyContent' warning in a Chakra-UI element in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, chakra-ui

```
 <Box
    d="flex"
    justify="space-between"
    alignItems="center"
    bg="white"
    w="100%"
    p="5px 10px 5px 10px"
    borderWidth="5px"
  >
    <Tooltip label="Search Users to chat" hasArrow placement="bottom-end">
      <Button variant="ghost">
        <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
        <Text d={{ base: "none", md: "flex" }} px={4}>
          Search User
        </Text>
      </Button>
    </Tooltip>
    <Text fontSize="2xl" fontFamily="Work sans">
      Converse-Crew
    </Text>
  <div>
   <Menu>
    <MenuButton p={1}>
     <BellIcon></BellIcon>

    </MenuButton>
   </Menu>
  </div>
  </Box>
```

in log I'm getting this...

Warning: React does not recognize the `web-justifyContent` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `web-justifycontent` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element..I'm not getting what's the issue here..

Comment: This is happening because `web-justifyContent` is being set on a DOM node. which is not a valid attribute

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Could be due to `justify` prop on `Box`